# How to interact Visual Source Safe with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

I use Visual Studio 2005 and I wanted to setup Visual Source Safe 8.0.

I run the setup and It works properly I can access VSS administration tool and visual source safe via start menu.

But, I can not see **File / Source Safe** menu in my Visual Studio 2005.

Does anyone know how can I interact my visual source safe and visual studio ?

**SOLVED :**

I solve my problem in this way :

I open Tools / Options / Source Control / Plugin Selection in my Visual Studio

and In Current Source Safe Plugin list I select Visual Source Safe.

Comment: A lot of people would probably beg, or even pay you, NOT to use Visual Source Safe.

Comment: MSFT has already shifted to Team Foundation system. They will drop visual source safe very soon.

Comment: Very soon? Last time it shipped was with VS2005...

Comment: @Nick : Yes, I want to start using CVS, but now I can not dare to start a new source control tool. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find SourceSafe related items through the following:

- File -> Source Control
- Tools -> Options -> Source Control

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, you might have to set the provider - [like so](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/configure-current-source-control-provider-in-visual-studio-2005/). With that, it should appear as "Source Control" in a few places.

Additional: However; this would be a good time to suggest something like SVN; easy to setup both client and server... many other tools exist, at all budgets. All seemingly preferable to VSS.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered how to get VSS working with VS2005, but please, unless you're joining an existing project, **seriously consider using another source control solution**.

You should read some articles about it. Of the top of my bookmarks:

- [Coding Horror: Source Control: Anything But SourceSafe](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html)
- [Visual SourceSafe: Microsoft's Source Destruction System](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/windev/sourcesafe.html)
- [Visual SourceSafe Version Control: Unsafe at any Speed?](http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html)

VSS <del>makes baby jesus cry</del> is evil.
If you don't want to invest more money just use SVN with a good VS plugin like [AnkhSVN](http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what you mean by the "crying" remark, but perhaps you should clarify it for those who may be unfamiliar with the expression...